# Topology of the real points of Shimura varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Snowden [has studied](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3131) the topology of the real points of modular curves. Are there analogous results for other Shimura varieties defined over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Curious that Shimura varieties are trendy enough to make the hot network questions list...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni ... in plague times. Sigh.

Comment: Historical note: the case of the real points of $X(N)$ was first considered by Jaffee in *Degeneration of real elliptic curves*. Jaffee also wrote other articles on real forms of symmetric domains, which may be of interest.

Answer (score 5):

Well, classical Shimura curves associated to non-trivial quaternion algebras have no real points, so that's pretty easy to describe, albeit not very interesting. Ogg has a paper describing the real locus on the quotient of such curves by an involution:

[MR0717598 Ogg, A. P. (1-CA) Real points on Shimura curves. Arithmetic and geometry, Vol. I, 277–307, Progr. Math., 35, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1983.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-9284-3_12)

Answer (score 5):

Unclear whether this will be useful to you, but G. Shimura did write a paper about real points: "On the real points of an arithmetic quotient of a bounded symmetric domain", Math. Ann. 215 (1975), 135–164.